# Defaulting a selected value to a value from an observable but then allowing it to be changed

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have been trying to embrace the whole reactive development in Angular. For the most part it has worked really well but there have been a few things I have struggled with which on the face of it feels it should be simple.

I have one requirement where I display a list of items, the list can be also be filtered. The user is able to select an item from the list, the list indicates the currently selected item and also emits the item from the component for the parent component to consume. On entry into the componet the first entry in the list should be selected by default.

I have created a simple sample

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-95hzc1

In this example on first load the 'ford fiesta' should the selected car and emit this selection.
In my head it feels that the selectedCar is something that I should set on first emit of car$ but that does work.

It doesn't feel right to achieve this with a tap operator in the combineLatest.

Comment: Search after `startWith`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to push the value through the subject, you could set the value in your view model when there is not a selected car:

```js
public vm$ = combineLatest([this.filteredCars$, this.selectedCar$]).pipe(
  map(([filteredCars, selectedCar]) => ({
    filteredCars, 
    selectedCar: selectedCar ?? filteredCars[0]
  })
);
```

Comment: this would work for the view model. I will also need to emit the selected car from the component. The plan was to do this directly on the observable. Something along the lines of

`@Output() selectedCar = this.selectedCar$;`

I think in your solution selectedCar will not emit for that initial value

Comment: maybe you could do: `@Output() selectedCar = this.vm$.pipe(map(s => s.selectedCar), distinctUntilChanged());`. Of course, you'd need to ensure that all of your source observables (`filteredCars$` and `selectedCar$`) each emit some initial value.